# Install Xcode10.2.1 but still got the error 'Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, version

I got an error when using Xcode11.2.

> Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler

Because I can't recompile the framework, I downgrade the version of Xcode to **10.2.1** to fix the problem, but I still got the same error as mentioned above.

I also tried to use toolchain but it shows unsupported configuration as following:

> The Swift standard library from the toolchain cannot be used on devices.
>
> Select a macOS or simulator run destination instead, or use a different toolchain that only provides the compiler.

How can I import the framework correctly?

Btw, do anyone know why the simulator and device not showing when using Xcode 10.2.1? Do I miss any step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select lower deployment target and you will be able to show the simulator [image]

Comment: Thank you! You fix both problems of simulator and import!